# Code Contracts и TeamCity

Tags: c#, непрерывная-интеграция, msbuild, teamcity

Коллеги, добрый день.

Настраиваю TeamCity 10 для сборки ASP.NET проекта созданного в VS 2015. 
В проекте, кроме всего прочего, используется библиотека CodeContracts. На сборочном сервере VisualStudio не установлено. Насколько я понимаю, в этом случае TeamCity использует установленный на машине msbuild. В результате, при сборке на сервере рерайтинг контрактов не происходит.

Нашел несколько рекомендаций в интернете. Делал следующее:

1. Скачал с сайта [visualstudiogallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) и установил библиотеку CodeContracts на сервере. В файле проекта прописал дополнительный импорт

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <CodeContractsInstallDir Condition="'$(CodeContractsInstallDir)'==''">C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\</CodeContractsInstallDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Condition="'$(CodeContractsImported)' != 'true' AND '$(DontImportCodeContracts)' != 'true'" Project="$(CodeContractsInstallDir)MsBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.CodeContracts.targets" />
```

Не помогло. Ничего не рерайтилось.

---

2. Установил библиотеку контрактов как nuget пакет в проект ([ссылка](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNet.Contracts)). Пакет официальный от Microsoft. Все тулзы для рерайта лежат внутри этого пакета. В файле проекта добавил похожий импорт, однако ссылающийся на `.target` файлы внутри данного nuget пакета.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <CodeContractsInstallDir Condition="'$(CodeContractsInstallDir)' == ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\packages\DotNet.Contracts.1.10.20606.1\'))</CodeContractsInstallDir>`
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Condition="'$(CodeContractsImported)' != 'true' AND '$(DontImportCodeContracts)' != 'true'" Project="$(CodeContractsInstallDir)\MsBuild\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.CodeContracts.targets"/>
```

Аналогично - не помогло.

Интересная деталь - в куске конфига в пункте 2 переменная `CodeContractsInstallDir` "указывает" на папку вышеописанного nuget пакета. Логично предположить, что операции с контрактами будут вестись с помощью тулзов из этой папки. Однако при сборке студией на своей машине в логах я вижу использование тулзов контрактной библиотеки из стандартного расположения "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrewrite.exe". Как это происходит - тоже не совсем понятно...

**Возможно кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой и может подсказать решение и поделится опытом?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В результате никакие частичные решения не помогли.
Пришлось установить 2015 студию со всеми либами и рантаймом на сборочный сервер.
После этого все подхватывалось и работало корректно.

Кстати в следующем проекте от CodeContracts отказался, слишком мало бенефитов для меня...